# AWS Sagemaker Image Classification Hyper-parameters Configuration

Tags: image-processing, amazon-sagemaker, hyperparameters, resnet

**Image Classification Hyper-parameters Configuration**

I have use SageMaker built-in Image Classification to train model own datasets which contain raw images of three classes objects. Each class contains different phone model images like iphone6plus, iphone7plus and samsung s7edge.

Those images are captured by phone camera and then resize to 224*224 dimension for training. The total num of training samples are 1920 and num of classes is 3. After many times of training, the average model validation accuracy I get is 0.4 or lower which is not accurate.

[image]

What is the recommendation values that I need to put in parameters in order to increase the model accuracy? This was my first time to train the model and I need some guidance on it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 1920 training samples, I would definitely recommend that you increase your training `epochs` up from 15. As it is, 15 epochs really isn't a huge time to learn.

You could also try increasing the `learning rate` a bit more if the model isnt learning fast enough.

Keep increasing the epochs / learning rate until your validation loss doesn't lower any more and/or the early stopping kicks in, which should see you get a rise in accuracy. Keep an eye on the `train:rmse` graph in the training job on the SageMaker console to get an idea if your training is stopping too early.

However, there might be other reasons why you are getting a low accuracy outside of hyperparameters. Things like overfitting or improperly sampled / split data could also be possible causes.

Answer (score 0):

You should start with a pretrained model and use learning rate in the regime of 0.01-0.001 and train for 50-100 epochs. With small datatsets you want to finetune the model pretrained on ImageNet dataset (1.2 million images).